# Replacement for numpy.apply_along_axis in CuPy

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I have a NumPy-based neural network that I am trying to port to CuPy. I have a function as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def tensor_diag(x): return np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, -1, x)

# Usage: (x is a matrix, i.e. a 2-tensor)
def sigmoid_prime(x): return tensor_diag(sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x)))
```

This works using NumPy, but CuPy does not have an analogue for the function (it is unsupported as of 8th May 2020). How can I emulate this behaviour in CuPy?

Comment: There's nothing special about `apply_along_axis`.  In this call, it just iterates on all axes of `x` except the last, passing the last to `np.diag`.  What's the `shape` of `x`?  It's docs explain what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [284]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```

`np.diag` takes a 1d array, and returns a 2d with the values on the diagonal. `apply_along_axis` just iterates on all dimensions except the last, and passes the last, one array at a time to `diag`:

```
In [285]: np.apply_along_axis(np.diag,-1,arr)                                                          
Out[285]: 
array([[[[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  1,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  2,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  3]],

        [[ 4,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  5,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  6,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  7]],

        [[ 8,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  9,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0, 10,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0, 11]]],


       [[[12,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0, 13,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0, 14,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0, 15]],

        [[16,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0, 17,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0, 18,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0, 19]],

        [[20,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0, 21,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0, 22,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0, 23]]]])
In [286]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[286]: (2, 3, 4, 4)
```

I could do the same mapping with:

```
In [287]: res = np.zeros((2,3,4,4),int)                                                                
In [288]: res[:,:,np.arange(4),np.arange(4)] = arr
```

check with the `apply` result:

```
In [289]: np.allclose(_285, res)                                                                       
Out[289]: True
```

Or for a more direct copy of `apply`, use `np.ndindex` to generate all the `i,j` tuple pairs to iterate over the first 2 dimensions of `arr`:

```
In [298]: res = np.zeros((2,3,4,4),int)                                                                
In [299]: for ij in np.ndindex(2,3): 
     ...:     res[ij]=np.diag(arr[ij]) 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [300]: np.allclose(_285, res)                                                                       
Out[300]: True
```